# Remove the extra number after the name of Ethernet connection

Tags: windows-8

This actually might be a strange question to ask. It's not affecting anything but I do feel a bit awkward to see my Ethernet connection named as "Derek 2". It can be seen that there is no other networks named as "Derek" so I really want to know if there's a way for me to rename my Ethernet connection.

[image: Screenshot of my network connections]

[image: Screenshot of Network and Sharing center]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally solved this problem by deleting network profiles from regedit.

Source: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1101977-windows-8-rename-network/

The network profiles are stored under: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\

Comment: Thank you - your answer worked but don't forget to reboot. You can also RegEdit search for "Network  2" - notice that is TWO spaces.

Comment: @DanielSokolowski for pointing out the two spaces. Silly html kills the second one and without you saying it I wouldn't have realized

Comment: So it turns out that on my Windows 8.1 machine it was only one space. And the key was at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\ but searching for the name got me there easily.

Comment: Perfect! This is the only solution that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have more than one network profile stored on your machine for the same network.

If you go to....Control Panel>>Network and Sharing Center.....under your active network you can see the icon that might look like a house or office building. Clicking on this will take you to the network properties page. From here you can rename the network or change the icon. But to keep this from happening again, you can also merge or delete network locations from this configuration box as well. You can either delete "Derek" and Derek 2"...and than rejoin your network...or just merge the two.

Comment: Actually I haven't seen any icon that might look like a house or office building...

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my network and sharing center...

Comment: AH, overlooked Windows 8

Comment: You can simply rename the connection under change adapter settings

Comment: But again, this is because for whichever reason your machine has stored multiple profiles. So it may happen again if you were to reconnect. So this may not be a permanent solution. I have only just recently made the transition to windows 8 with one of my machines. So I will be looking for a solution like I posted abouve.

Comment: Renaming actually does not solve the problem. When you rename the Ethernet connection in Windows 8, you are renaming the "Ethernet" part, not "Derek 2". It's extremely weird...

Comment: So it appears that with win8, you may have "hidden devices" in your device manager causing this problem. If you open an elevated cmd and enter "set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1"....and then with "devmgmt.msc" you will enter command prompt. Now, under "View" click "show hidden devices" and you should be able to see these network devices that you can get rid of. Once you're done, go back to an elevated cmd and enter "ncpa.cpl".