# Remove the Number `(2)` / `2` from the Ethernet and Network Card on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, drivers, ethernet

I have Windows 10 Update 20H2.

My network card name is:

[image]

As you can see it is called `Ethernet 2` and `Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V`.

I wonder how can IK remove the `2` from `Ethernet 2` and the `(2)` form the network card.

I tried:

[image]

By entering `netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet 2" newname="Ethernet"`.
Yet I got: `You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. If joining a domain, go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again. If joining a workgroup, choose another workgroup name.`.

Regarding the numeration of the Network card, I have no idea how to remove it.

Any idea?

Things I have Tried:

- [Remove an unused/hidden network connection so that an existing name can be reused](https://superuser.com/questions/1257859).
- [Remove the extra number after the name of Ethernet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/573934).
- [Ten Forums - How to Rename a Network Adapter in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/106456-rename-network-adapter-windows.html).
- [Microsoft DevBlogs Scripting - Renaming Network Adapters by Using PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/renaming-network-adapters-by-using-powershell/).

This is the result of `Get-NetAdapter | format-list`:

```
Name                       : Ethernet 2
InterfaceDescription       : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-V
InterfaceIndex             : 15
MacAddress                 : E0-D5-5E-44-A5-54
MediaType                  : 802.3
PhysicalMediaType          : 802.3
InterfaceOperationalStatus : Up
AdminStatus                : Up
LinkSpeed(Mbps)            : 100
MediaConnectionState       : Connected
ConnectorPresent           : True
DriverInformation          : Driver Date 2019-09-05 Version 12.18.9.11 NDIS 6.50
```

Comment: What are the contents of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkSetup2\Interfaces`?  If you run the command, `netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" newname="Ethernet 3"`, what happens?  Can you also provide the full output of `Get-NetAdapter | format-list`?

Comment: I added the result.

Comment: Uninstall, then reinstall, the network adapter drivers after a reboot _(verify via Device Manager)_. If that doesn't fix it, you'll need to find the registry key for the original adapter name and remove it _(using the search functionality of `regedit` or the RegCrawler search function of [`RegEditX`](https://www.dcsoft.com/products/regeditx))_

Answer (score 1):

Go to service manager. Select "show hidden devices". You can then delete the old, unused devices that are interfering. See below:

To identify and remove the ghost devices from the Windows Device Manager, do the following:

1. From the command prompt:

C:>set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

C:>start devmgmt.msc

2. Then, select View from the drop down and select to Show Hidden Devices.
3. At this point, any ghost network interface devices will be seen with lighter, transparent icon and can be removed.  This is done by right-clicking the ghost tape device and selecting " Uninstall".
4. A reboot of the machine should be performed following this action.
5. Prior to re-configuring any devices, ensure no additional ghost entries have been created following the reboot. Repeat the procedure if needed, or consult Microsoft if the source of the entries cannot be found and they cannot be removed from the operating system.